# Slick Grid not displaying data inside tab in angular

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I am using Angular Slickgrid to display data inside tabs(more than one tab). I am getting data from the service but the table is not showing any data. Few tabs show data but not the table heading

Here is the code:

```
 Parent File

   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="h2">
      <div class="row">
        <article class="col-sm-12">
            <sa-users-list [id]="gridUsersList"></sa-users-list>               
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="h3">
      <div class="row">
        <article class="col-sm-12">
          <sa-facility-list [id]="gridFacility"></sa-facility-list>             
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
```

user list File

```
<div id="content2">
          <angular-slickgrid gridId="gridUsersList" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)"
            [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="usersListdataset">
          </angular-slickgrid>
        </div>
```

Facility List

```
<div id="content">
          <angular-slickgrid gridId="gridFacility" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)"
            [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="facilitydataset">
          </angular-slickgrid>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checking you are using [this repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) - the MLeibman branch has issues initialising hidden grids. See for example [here](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-dynamic-filtered-with-jquery-tabs.html)

This is not an Angular repo, but these issues are probably still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid doesn't work well with DOM elements that are hidden, after changing Tabs you should make sure to call a grid resize, it might not be necessary on first Tab but is totally needed for all subsequent Tabs.

You can see the live demo [here](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/gridtabs), that is the new [Example 24](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/gridtabs) I recently added.

For example with `ngx-bootstrap`, notice the call to `(selectTab)="resizeGrid2()"`

```html
<div>
    <tabset>
      <tab heading="Javascript" id="javascript">
        <h4>Grid 1 - Load Local Data</h4>
        <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
          [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions1"
          [gridOptions]="gridOptions1"
          [dataset]="dataset1">
        </angular-slickgrid>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Http-Client" (selectTab)="resizeGrid2()">
        <h4>Grid 2 - Load a JSON dataset through Http-Client</h4>
        <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid2"
          [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions2"
          [gridOptions]="gridOptions2"
          [dataset]="dataset2"
          (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGrid2Ready($event)">
        </angular-slickgrid>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
```

Component (demo component [link](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-tabs.component.ts))

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  angularGrid2: AngularGridInstance;
  columnDefinitions1: Column[];
  columnDefinitions2: Column[];
  gridOptions1: GridOption;
  gridOptions2: GridOption;
  dataset1: any[];
  dataset2: any[];


  angularGrid2Ready(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid2 = angularGrid;
  }

  resizeGrid2() {
    this.angularGrid2.resizerService.resizeGrid();
  }
```

Quick note, I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) which uses 6pac/SlickGrid fork (which Ben pointed out in previous answer).

Another important thing is to make sure that all your grids have unique `gridId`, which might be your problem. So you might also want to take a look at this other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148727/angular-slickgrid-not-displaying-inside-dynamic-tabngx-bootstrap-tabset/56150181#56150181) which is related since it's also for Tabs

Comment: Thanks you! still not work after add resizeGrid